# unable to update variable in angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am learning angular and I am having an issue updating a variable.

the function `toggleVariable` should toggle `isUserNameEmpty` but its not working at all

```
export class ServersComponent implements OnInit {

  userName = '';
  isUserNameEmpty=true;


   onUserNameUpdate(event:any){
    this.userName = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
    this.toggleVariable( this.userName,this.isUserNameEmpty);
  }

  toggleVariable(variableName,variableToToggle){
   
    if(variableName!=''){
      console.log('not empty');
      console.log('variableName: '+variableName);
      console.log('variableToToggle: '+variableToToggle);
      variableToToggle=false;
    }
    else if (variableName==''){
      console.log('empty');
      console.log('variableName: '+variableName);
      console.log('variableToToggle: '+variableToToggle);
      variableToToggle=true;
    }
  }


  clearUserName(){
    this.userName = '';
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not pass the variable directly inside the if statement?

Comment: im just curious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not modifying the `isUserNameEmpty` property.  You are only modifying the value of `variableToToggle` within the scope of the method. try this

```
  toggleVariable(variableName) {

      this.isUserNameEmpty = variableName === '';

  }
```

Comment: so there is no way of making a function that is independent of the class variable?

thats odd

Comment: @JuanCasas only objects are passed as reference, primitives are passed as values

Comment: There are ways to make the method more generic by returning a value which would then be used to set the value of a property, in this case, isUserNameEmpty.

Comment: @LewisCortright for president 2024!!  thank you!!!

I added you on linkedIn!!